# INSERT INTO SELECT how to insert in right order?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have simple query:

```
INSERT INTO test(id) SELECT rowid FROM words ORDER BY word
```

TABLE test has two fields 'nr' and 'id' - 'nr' is auto_increment

I want records to be added in order specified by "ORDER BY" but they are ordered by rowid...

I get result like:

```
nr id    
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

etc ...

How to do it in right order ?

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
    `rowid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `word` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',
    `display` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',
    `difficult` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `islocked` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valid` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
    INDEX `word` (`word`),
    INDEX `display` (`display`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_polish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=57009
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: realy is it problem at THIS question?

Comment: [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d22cwDAwEUcqiQ4Hq4ADg1/0)

Comment: That assumes words are unique ... @PaulSpiegel `ORDER BY` on non unique data can still give non derministic ("random") order where ties exists..

Comment: *"realy is it problem at THIS question?"* It is stackoverflow [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> *"Proof-read before posting!

Now that you're ready to ask your question, take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. **Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense? Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question**"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland "works for me" means - I cannot reproduce the "problem". So it's up to OP to post a reproducible example, which doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: ok i'm sory ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland - yes word is not unique - can you help me ?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel mine comment was not meant to "attack" you or anything in fact i totaly agree with you.. i also do not understand what the topicstarter is trying to explain here or which problem that the topicstarter runs into... A non derministic order on non unique data for me could be a very logical reason why the topicstarter was also seeing a "wrong" order..

Comment: *"yes word is not unique - can you help me ? "*  See mine and @PaulSpiegel suggestions, post a **good** reproducible example ...

Comment: i can't - Pauls example woks fine but when i use my table (it is very big) in this example - not working... i edit Pauls example and i use my create statement to create table words - it still woks fine i don't unterstand

Comment: @barpas maybe include the words you have in your table? At least minimal number of them, that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@barpas It is not possible to achieve what you want because your words.word column is not unique.  For example, Let's say the word "Apple" appears 4 times in your words table like this:

```
"rowid"  "word"
10     Apple
94     Apple
130    Apple
526    Apple
```

Which of the four IDs should be inserted into test.id?  Instead of 1 result you have 4.  In Paul's example, there are no duplicates values ("a", "b", "c") are all different and none of them repeat.  Change Paul's example to have ('a', 'a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c') instead... That is more like your data.